# git : Small project work

Tags: git

I'm currently trying to follow the small project based work-group mentioned in the Pro Git book : http://progit.org/book/ch5-2.html

So, here's my set-up:

```
[Live Website Folder] 
|             |
|             |
Developer1    Developer2
```

The way that I achieved that was I did the following:

1. git init --shared=0777
2. git clone /live/website developer1
3. git clone /live/website developer2

I was able to successfully clone my project and I went into `developer1` folder. Here I make changes to my file `index.html`. Once, I make these changes, I do:

```
git add index.html
git commit -m 'Modified index.html --developer1'
git push
```

Now when I go to my `/live/website` directory and do a `git status`, it correctly tells me that the file `index.html` is modified. When I do:

```
git add index.html
git commit -m 'Modified index.html by developer1'
```

It successfully makes the commit, but when I try to `vi index.html`, the file that I see is the original/un-modified one. I don't see the changes made by developer1, within that file. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `git status` is telling you is that `index.html` is different to what is in the git index.

After you push, your `/live/website` repo contains the updated `index.html` in the index, but the old `index.html` in the working copy. You need to do `git reset --hard HEAD` followed by `git checkout -f` inside `/live/website` to reset the working copy to the same as the HEAD commit.

I'd suggest that you modify your setup slightly. Add a `staging` repository that is bare and push changes into that. Add a post-update hook that runs `git pull staging master` inside `/live/website`. This will ensure that the live website gets updated as soon as a commit is pushed in.

In glorious ascii art:

```
 /live/website
       |
       |
/path/to/staging (bare)
  |          |
  |          |
dev1        dev2
```

EDIT: Updated to correct command sequence for fixing the working copy.

Comment: Cameron, is there a particular reason your suggesting adding the bare repo inbetween?

Comment: It just makes things a bit easier. Without it you wind up with the weird situation you've just encountered: the working copy doesn't match the index in your live website. It's possible to fix without the staging repo (using `git reset` and `git checkout`) but that approach is a little riskier: `git reset` may throw data away which is generally A Bad Thing.

Comment: By the way, the hook should be in the `staging` repo.

Comment: So Cameron, I would be cloning /live/website into dev1 and dev2. However, I would push into /path/to/staging? Or would I clone /live/website to /path/to/staging and then clone /path/to/staging into dev1 and dev2?

Comment: 1) Set up `staging` with `--bare`. 2) Run `git clone` in each of dev1, dev2 and live (clone staging). 3) Set up the post-update hook in staging that does something like `cd /live/website && git pull origin master`. 4) Push from devN into staging. 5) Enjoy!

Comment: If you already have content in `/live/website` then you can create a commit inside `live` and push it back into `staging` before you add the hook. `git add .` will add all your existing content. `dev` and `dev2` will then receive that content when they next pull from staging. You could do this as step 2.5. Alternatively, copy all your content into dev1 and push from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cameron, I think I've got my project working figured out much better now. Just one last question, if I do a push from dev1 or dev2 and I need to roll-back to a previous version, would I do this from the staging repo or the /website/live repo? Also, could you please tell me how this can be done? I think my "true" log is shown when I do a git log in the staging directory. So I think a undo would probably need to be done from here as well?

Comment: Depends what kind of rollback you want. If it's a temporary rollback (e.g. someone broke the site and is working on a fix) then you could do it in `live` using `git reset`. This will be un-rolled-back next time a commit is pushed in. If it's a permanent rollback (e.g. someone changed index.html to say "users are teh suk") then you can use `git revert` to undo the bad commit. You generally should not delete commits once they have been pushed or pulled anywhere, so `git revert` is the best way to remove a bad commit. You should generally not touch `staging`: it is your back-end repo.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are pushing into a non-bare repository. This is [not recommended](http://www.gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html) and can have unexpected effects to trap the unwary. Instead, you might want to create a new, bare repository to serve as the main repository.

```
mkdir /git/project.git
cd /git/project.git
git init --bare --shared
cd /live/website
git remote add origin /git/project.git
git push origin master
```

Then, developer1 and developer2 should clone from `/git/project.git`, and push there too. When you want to update your live website:

```
cd /live/website
git pull
```

Comment: Greg, you are correct. It is a non-bare repository. The reason being, I want to see the latest version of my working files in /live/website.

Comment: You can set up a hook in your bare repository to update the `/live/website` immediately if you like.

Comment: Could you mention why is it such a no-no to be using it as a non-bare repo. I mean, if someone who was not used to git, went into the folder. He'd be amazed as to how its working? I just want the option to have the working files there too, so that a user not familiar with git could see them as well. Additionally, would the hook, just be a git pull?

Comment: When pushing to a non-bare repository, Git does *not* change the files in the working tree (this is exactly the problem that you originally saw). All it does is store the commit object(s) inside its internal representation. Git does this because it doesn't want to lose any work that might be going on in the working tree (consider the case of somebody else editing a file at the same time). And yes, the hook would just be a `git pull` into `/live/website`. For the user unfamiliar with Git, they wouldn't even have to know that you've got a bare repository in the middle.

Comment: Thankgs Greg ... I understand thanks to Cameron the significance of the bare repo in the middle ..

Answer (score 0):

When you push to another directory it does not update the checkout of that remote directory.

You would have to do (on live/website):

```
git reset --hard
```

to get the new updates from developers.

This happens because your tree is currently pointing to a previous commit tree. but when doing 'git status' it fetches the most recent changes from the branch you are on.

One way to get out of this is to set up a git-hook on post-receive

Comment: sorry i put the bad command from memory. here's the good one. From http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/

Comment: @g1t but has the other says this is not the prefered git workflow

Comment: Thankt pastjean, I've followed the other way. But your link of hooks helped!