# git hook permission problem

Tags: git, bash

I've set my git working structure as follows (thanks to a recommendation in another question [git : Small project work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394300/git-small-project-work))

```
 /live/website
       |
       |
/path/to/staging (bare)
  |          |
  |          |
dev1        dev2
```

Currently, both dev1 and dev2, push the projects to the `/path/to/staging repo`. I have a hook in /path/to/staging, that automatically triggers a `git pull` from my  /live/website. This way, I have a working copy of files there.

Also `/path/to/staging (bare)` was initialized with share=0777, so I know for a fact the share is not a problem. Also, I've CHMODded all files to 777 and set the stick bit as well.

I've created the /live/website repo as `user : root`. However, I've created the repo in dev1 as `user : dev1`. I can make changes in dev1 fine, however when I try to push the repo from dev1, here's the problem I face:

```
error: Couldn't set refs/remotes/origin/master
From /path/to/staging
 ! 8b4fddc2 .. e2a0b21  master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
To path/to/staging
   8c5fddc2  .. e2a0b21 master -> master
```

And basically, I don't see the files transfer successfully to /live/website. I think this problem arises since I'm executing the code as `user : dev1`. However, when I browse to `/live/websit`e and do a `git pull` manually as `user : root`, it does successfully pull the changes made by dev1 and changes the working file.

Can someone recommend if there is a way to work around this problem? Since it beats the purpose of the automatic hook ...

Something else that I thought of doing was in the hook, I was thinking of changing the user:

```
su root
password
```

However, when it executes, I don't think I'm entering the password at the prompt, since the error message I receive is :

```
hooks/post-receive: line 18: password: command not found
```

---

EDIT ,

Also, can someone suggest a way to go back from a push? And get the previous state of files?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't give su a password on the command line. But you can use sudo, add the permitted user into [/etc/sudoers](http://man.cx/sudoers) **with no password**, so you can run your command as `sudo -u webside-user-name 'cd /live/website && git fetch && git checkout master'`.

Comment: Rudi: I looked at that file and it says, I can only modify by doing sudo visudo. However, when I try and execute that : `sudo: visudo: command not found`. So editing that is something I'm having trouble with. In terms of the git directory structure, do you know why I'm having trouble executing the pull? I mean, the `/live/website` is a shared repository. I ensured , I made it such by doing `git repo-config core.sharedRepository true`

Comment: Can you su into the root account and run visudo there? On debian visudo is in the sudo package (http://packages.debian.org/lenny/i386/sudo/filelist) and lives in /usr/sbin/visudo.

Comment: As for the `/live/website` part: Do you have set up the `/path/to/staging` repo yet? If so the `/live/website` must be a non-bare repo, since you want the files appearing there. I suggest to move the current `/live/website` path away and replace it with a regular clone of `/live/website`.

Comment: The files in .git/objects are all 0777, so I'm not sure why is there still a permission error ...

Comment: Did you cloned `/live/website` from a developer account or the webserver account? Does it work when you `chown -R webserver-user-account /live/website`?

Comment: It seems that receive.denyNonFastforwards is set to true on `path/to/staging/`. You can check this with `cd path/to/staging/ && git config --get-all receive.denyNonFastforwards`. If the result is true, then this repo is configured to refuse non-fast-forward updates. While you can change this configuration, a change will **not solve your problem***: The commit you pruned with this push is still in a repo of another developer, so if this developer pushes his branch again, the faulty commit will reappear. The other developer will not even notice that you removed this commit from the branch.

Comment: A better way is to `git revert` the faulty commit (git revert creates a commit which undo the specified commit). Also you can add a development branch in `path/to/staging/`, and only merge the development branch to master after a review. See http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default and http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ for more branch strategies.

Comment: Rudi .. `receive.denyNonFastforwards = true` on the `/path/to/staging`. I also tried the git revert there and since it is --bare, here's what I get : `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`. I know I can probably run the commit from developer1 instead. However, I wanted to have a kind of master reset where I could just log onto `/path/to/staging` or `/live/website` and step-down to a stable version instead of figuring out which developer made the change and then doing a `git revert`. Is this possible? Would I be able to go to a older commit, pull the change from dev1 and then cont

Comment: @g1t: If you really need to push non-fast-forward updates to that specific repo, why don't you just set `receive.denyNonFastForwards` to false?

Answer (score 1):

I am using a similar workflow and I don't even have root access on the live webserver and it still works fine. Here's the script I'm using (it's a post-receive hook; I suppose it could be a post-update hook instead but I haven't tested that):

```
#!/bin/sh
# To enable this hook, make this file executable by "chmod +x post-receive".
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/htdocs git checkout -f
```

Then you can test the hook by running hooks/post-receive. If it works when you test it manually, it should work when you run "git push"